# Parse the first line of a CSV after upload with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv

I need to have uploads of csvs that are up to 350MB with around 3,000,000 lines. I only need to check the header on the first line. Is there an efficient way to do this? Using node-csv take a long time because it's parsing the whole thing. I'm using busyboy and have a stream.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never had to parse a file so large but maybe you can try a combination of the [event-stream](https://github.com/dominictarr/event-stream) and [get-line](https://www.npmjs.com/package/get-line) packages:

```
var es, fs, getLine, getLines;

getLine = require('get-line');
fs = require('fs');
es = require('event-stream');

getLines = getLine({
    lines: [1],
    encoding: 'utf8'
});

console.time('get first line');
fs.createReadStream('./test.csv', { encoding: 'utf8' })
    .pipe(getLines)
    .pipe(es.map(function(line, next) {
        var data = line.split(',').map(function(c) { return c.trim(); });
        /* this will be called for each line, do your stuff here */
        console.log(data);

        return next(null, line);
    })).pipe(es.wait(function(err, body) {
        /* this is called after the processing of all lines, if you want to do something more */
        /* can be removed if you don't need it */
        console.timeEnd('get first line');
    }));
```

Edit: just tried my code with a fat csv from [here](https://sdm.lbl.gov/fastbit/data/samples.html) (the `star2002` file, 2GB), here is the result:

```
[ '1',
  '1613423',
  '807',
  '20011015.2226039991',
  '1613424',
  '4518',
  '0',
  '0',
  '654',
  '1395',
  '20011204.1149509996',
  '10.955403',
  '2288071',
  '-0.28820264',
  '0.40731233',
  '10.559091' ]
get first line: 15ms
```

Comment: The get-line module does what I need and is much faster than needlessly parsing the 3 million lines. I'll use it for now but it seems like there should be simpler way.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might arise with the method you used node-csv package. 
In the samples they have a sample of parsing large csv file as a stream. 
Here is the sample [from github](https://github.com/wdavidw/node-csv/blob/master/samples/stream.js):

```
var csv = require('..');
var i = 0

var generator = csv.generate({seed: 1, columns: 2, length: 20});
var parser = csv.parse();
var transformer = csv.transform(function(data){
  i++
  return data.map(function(value){return value.toUpperCase()});
});
var stringifier = csv.stringify();

generator.on('readable', function(){
  while(data = generator.read()){
    parser.write(data);
  }
});
generator.on('end', function(){
  parser.end()
});

parser.on('readable', function(){
  while(data = parser.read()){
    transformer.write(data);
  }
});
parser.on('end', function(){
  transformer.end()
});

transformer.on('readable', function(){
  while(data = transformer.read()){
    stringifier.write(data);
  }
});
transformer.on('end', function(){
  stringifier.end();
});

stringifier.on('readable', function(){
  while(data = stringifier.read()){
    process.stdout.write(data);
  }
});
generator.on('end', function(){
  process.stdout.write('=> ' + i + ' records\n');
});
```

Comment: I tried that but to read through each line, even doing nothing else is just too slow and pointless.